# build every group of data and add them to the rendered XML page using xmlbuilder2

Tags: node.js, xml, xml-binding, xml-builder, updatexml

I'm using `xmlbuilder2` node module to build the retrieved data and render them into XML page. when the data is very big I got this error

`FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

I was thinking of retrieve the data and render them in chunks to avoid the issue instead of waiting for all of them. but is it possible to edit an already rendered XML page?

Comment: Did you try the [callback API](https://oozcitak.github.io/xmlbuilder2/builder-functions-with-callbacks.html)?

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following command line argument for node:

```
--max_old_space_size=8048
```

With the number to be the MB of RAM available to the node-process. I hope you are not generating XML bigger than your memory this way. Otherwise you will need a solution with streaming.